# How do I load a CSV in IOS after saving it locally

Tags: ios, objective-c, quicklook

I have a CSV file that I'm downloading from an S3 account and I would like to show it in my ios app by using the Quicklook framework.

The error I'm getting is in my console. It says

```
QLPreviewController's datasource shouldn't be nil at this point.
```

This appears after this line of code runs `// Set data source
        [previewer setDataSource:self];`

here's all the code for downloading the file, saving it and then loading with quicklook

```
-(void)showDocument
{
    NSString *stringURL = @"http://jornada.s3.amazonaws.com/Dust.csv";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:nil];
    if ( urlData )
    {
        NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"tempfile.csv"];

        //[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

        BOOL newFile = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:urlData attributes:nil];

        arrayOfDocuments = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            filePath, nil];


        QLPreviewController *previewer = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];

        [self addSubview:previewer.view];

        // Set data source
        [previewer setDataSource:self];

        // Which item to preview
        [previewer setCurrentPreviewItemIndex:0];
    }

}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
- (NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller
{
    return [arrayOfDocuments count];
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController: (QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{


    // Break the path into it's components (filename and extension)
    NSArray *fileComponents = [[arrayOfDocuments objectAtIndex: index] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    NSArray *filePaths = [[fileComponents objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[((NSString *)[filePaths objectAtIndex:[filePaths count]-1]) stringByAppendingString:(NSString*)[fileComponents objectAtIndex:1]]];

    // Use the filename (index 0) and the extension (index 1) to get path

    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];


    if (fileExists) {
        //
    }
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't add a preview controller's view to your view - you present the preview controller. And you should do that *after* setting the data source! So, in this order:

```
QLPreviewController* preview = [QLPreviewController new];
preview.dataSource = self;
[self presentViewController:preview animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: More sample code for using QLPreviewController at the end of this section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_handing_off_a_document

Comment: Ok so I added your code but [self presentViewController is not correct. I did [previewView.window setRootViewController:preview]; The "QLPreviewController's datasource shouldn't be nil at this point" error is gone and everything seems to "work" but the CSV file doesn't load into the view.

Comment: You have to write datasource code that supplies the CSV file, as discussed in the book section I referred to in my previous comment. Of course all this is assuming that there is *any* built-in quick-look for csv; I would not presume that there is. However, use of quick-look was your decision, and you might want to look for another way to display this content; I believe I've answered the question you actually asked.

Comment: the above actually worked. I had a typo in my file path after saving the file locally. Works like a charm now.